# Making a piano simulator and the javascript will not execute or display in console

Tags: javascript

I am following a tutorial right now to make a playable piano. Everything was going great until I got to the javascript portion. I need this to display in the console (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGxLS.png) or https://youtu.be/Mv1ZYpo8q4g?list=PLpwngcHZlPadAbdD_sFE_moH6RjgaTFCw&t=932.

Im getting nothing in my console

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Wrapper">
        <header>
            <h2>Piano</h2>
            <div class="column volume-slider">
                    <span>Volume</span> <input type="Range">
            </div>
            <div class="column keys-checkbox">
                <span>Show keys</span> <input type="checkbox" checked>
        </div>
        </header>
        <ul class="piano-keys">
            <li class="key white"><span>a</span></li>
            <li class="key black"><span>w</span></li>
            <li class="key white"><span>s</span></li>
            <li class="key black"><span>e</span></li>
            <li class="key white"><span>d</span></li>
            <li class="key white"><span>f</span></li>
            <li class="key black"><span>t</span></li>
            <li class="key white"><span>g</span></li>
            <li class="key black"><span>y</span></li>
            <li class="key white"><span>h</span></li>
            <li class="key black"><span>u</span></li>
            <li class="key white"><span>j</span></li>
            <li class="key white"><span>k</span></li>
            <li class="key black"><span>o</span></li>
            <li class="key white"><span>l</span></li>
            <li class="key black"><span>p</span></li>
            <li class="key white"><span>;</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
const pianoKeys = document.querySelectorAll("piano-keys .key");

pianoKeys.forEach(key => {
    console.log(key);
})
```

I already uninstalled nodejs because I thought that was causing an issue. I've been troubleshooting for an hour and cant figure out why its not working.

Comment: Missing a `.` before `piano-keys`. Voting to close due to a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is not quite right. You have `"piano-keys .key"`. You need `".piano-keys .key"`

Comment: I spent hours looking over this! thank you so much!!!! (insert facepalm)